# Java - JSON Parsing to and Fro

Tags: java, json, multidimensional-array

I have been combing over multiple approaches with different JSON libraries, and cannot seem to find an elegant way to convert to and from with my JSON file in testing.

JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "LonelyParentKey": "Account",
    "ProcessNames": [
      {"Name":  "ProcessOne",
      "Sequence": "1"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ProcessTwo",
        "Sequence": "2"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ProcessThree",
        "Sequence": "3"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ProcessFour",
        "Sequence": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In a QAF-based test using TestNG, am trying to import the values of the "ProcessName" key like this:

```
  String lonelyParentKey = (String) data.get("LonelyParentKey");
  ArrayList processNames = (ArrayList) data.get("ProcessNames");
```

I've seen that in the framework I'm using, I have multiple JSON library options, have been trying to use GSON after reading other SO posts.

So, next in the test code:

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray(processNames);
```

What I am attempting to to create an object that contains 4 child objects in a data structure where I can access the Name and Sequence keys of each child.

In looking at my `jsa` object, it appears to have the structure I'm after, but how could I access the Sequence key of the first child object? In the REPL in IntelliJ IDEA, doing `jsa.get(0)` gives me `"{"Name":  "ProcessOne","Sequence": "1"}"`

Seems like a situation where maps could be useful, but asking for help choosing the right data structure and suggestions on implementing.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which library you're using, but they all offer pretty much the same methods. JSONArray looks like org.json.JSONArray, so that would be

```
JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray(processNames);
int sequenceFirstEntry = jsa.getJSONObject(0).getInt("Sequence");
```

Some JsonArray implementations also implement Iterable, then this also works

```
JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray(processNames);
for (JSONObject entry : jsa) {
    int sequenceFirstEntry = entry.getInt("Sequence");    
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you both for posting. Ended up using `jsa.getJSONObject(indexNumHere).get("KeyNameIWant")` and suits my needs. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Any reason to not use DTO classes for your model?

e.g.

```
class Outer {
    String lonelyParentKey;
    List<Inner> processNames;

    // getter/setter
}
```

and

```
class Inner {
    String name;
    String sequence;

    // getter/setter
}
```

now your library should be able to deserialize your JSON string into a List. I have been using Jackson instead of GSON, but it should be similar in GSON:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
List<X> x = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<X>>() {});
```

Comment: Since I'm writing tests that may soon evolve, wanted to stay away from any custom typing for now, but looks to be a generally good approach. Thank you!